# LLM(BLOOM) infer with CPU instead GPUs and OOM happens

Tags: pytorch, bloom, large-language-model

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import os
os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:32"
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
device = torch.device('cuda')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("/data/ygmeng/xuanyuan",trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("/data/ygmeng/xuanyuan",trust_remote_code=True, device_map="auto")

with torch.no_grad():
    # gpus=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    # model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model.to(device), device_ids=gpus, output_device=gpus[0])
    # model.module.to(device)
    model = model.eval()
    inputs=tokenizer("<s>" + "Human: " + "Who are you？" + "\n\nAssistant: ",return_tensors='pt')
    output = model.generate(**inputs, do_sample=True, temperature=0.8, top_k=50, top_p=0.9, early_stopping=True, repetition_penalty=1.1, min_new_tokens=1, max_new_tokens=256)
    print(tokenizer.batch_decode(output,skip_special_tokens=True))
```

[image: envs]
[image: envs]

Sometimes this happens to AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained:

```
    [2023-06-25 16:14:34,031] [INFO] [real_accelerator.py:110:get_accelerator] Setting ds_accelerator to cuda (auto detect)
    new_value = value.to(device)
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 13.40 GiB (GPU 0; 79.15 GiB total capacity; 68.53 GiB already allocated; 9.66 GiB free; 68.53 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

When the model is loaded correctly:

```
You are calling .generate() with the input_ids being on a device type different than your model's device. input_ids is on cuda, whereas the model is on cpu. You may experience unexpected behaviors or slower generation. Please make sure that you have put input_ids to the correct device by calling for example input_ids = input_ids.to('cpu') before running .generate().
```

I wanted to model.to(device) but no enough memory.So I ran inputs.to("cpu") which ran really slowly.I'm not sure what I did wrong!
[image: gpus not using]
[image: infering with cpu]

Comment: It seems that I don't have enough memory on GPU.